# Comparing strings in bash script

Tags: bash

```
./build_binaries.sh: line 43: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

I have this line (`line 43`) in my `bash script` which looks correct to me, but it keeps throwing error.

```
if [ ${platform} == "macosx" ]; then
```

Error:

```
./foo.sh: line 43: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

This is on OSX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `$platform` is an empty string. The usual workaround is to put it in quotes:

```
if [ "${platform}" == "macosx" ]
```

Example:

```
$ unset x
$ [ $x == 3 ]
-bash: [: ==: unary operator expected
$ [ "$x" == "3" ]
$
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use a single `=`.  That's the classic notation.  Some shells allow `==`, but others do not.

Also, you should enclose the `${platform}` in double quotes; I think that it is an empty string, and this is confusing things.

```
platform=
if [  $platform  == mac ]; then echo hi; else echo lo; fi
if [ "$platform" == mac ]; then echo hi; else echo lo; fi
```

This produces the error you're seeing on the second line.